# Google Bots Crawling Invalid URL

Tags: google, google-search-console, googlebot, react-js, next.js

Google Bots crawl URLs by appending trailing **200** and **false** for all the article pages. I am unsure what the issue is here and why that is getting appended on every article page.

I have tried scanning the site with Ahrefs, SEMRUSH, Screamingfrog. None of the tools detect these URL's and there is no reference to them on the entire site.

The site is developed using Next.JS 13, Tailwind, and React. Has anyone come across this kind of issue?

It is also impacting the ratio of successful vs failed crawling requests severely. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To me, it looks like your code is producing the urls.

Comment: i had this though if code is produced, scanning the site from different tools should have been reported. Also, I went to view the source of these pages to detect if it anywhere these URL's are present from the client or server side. I couldn't find it

Comment: In the section **Why Pages Are Not Indexed**, there is a source column.  If it says **website**, then its likely that they were generated by your site.  I would encourage you to list with Yandex as well.  I found it very helpful because not only are they more critical, they also give a better reason for failure.  And their support will actually correspond with you.

Comment: An idea. I suspect the source of the links are from the URL version without the 200 or false. In GSC inspect those URLs, view crawled page, and look at the HTML. See if it contains links with 200s or false.